# Paste a Confidence Interval into cells of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, with a example one listed below.

```
x <- data.frame("Col1" = 1:10, "Col2" = 11:20, "Col3" = 21:30)
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5) #2.5%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 97.5% sample CI.

#How do I get x[1,1] to be followed by "(v[1],v[5])"
#The result should be 1 (1,5) in the new "x" data frame first entry.
```

In each cell of the data frame, I want to have the existing number followed number followed by a confidence interval in parentheses. I listed my questions in the code itself, but let me know if I should clarify anything. I tried using the paste command so:

```
x[1,1] <- paste(x[1,1], "(v[1],v[5])")
```

This creates a character string to paste, and does not have the actual values of v[1] and v[5]. How should I proceed?

Comment: what about the rest of `v`? why is it length 5 and the other columns are length 10? why would they all have the same confidence interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`glue`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) and [`mutate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

mutate(x, across(everything(), ~glue("{.x} ({v[1]},{v[5]})")))

       Col1     Col2     Col3
1   1 (1,5) 11 (1,5) 21 (1,5)
2   2 (1,5) 12 (1,5) 22 (1,5)
3   3 (1,5) 13 (1,5) 23 (1,5)
4   4 (1,5) 14 (1,5) 24 (1,5)
5   5 (1,5) 15 (1,5) 25 (1,5)
6   6 (1,5) 16 (1,5) 26 (1,5)
7   7 (1,5) 17 (1,5) 27 (1,5)
8   8 (1,5) 18 (1,5) 28 (1,5)
9   9 (1,5) 19 (1,5) 29 (1,5)
10 10 (1,5) 20 (1,5) 30 (1,5)
```

Note: If you want to use `paste` and base R, you can do:

```r
data.frame(sapply(x, function(cell) paste0(cell, " (", v[1], ",", v[5], ")")))
```

Just seems a bit less readable that way.

Comment: sure you could learn two packages or `x[] <- sprintf('%s (%s, %s)', unlist(x), v[1], v[2]); x`